# How to filter a list by a lookup field in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, lookupfield

The first form list is "Standard", with a field of "Code";
The second document list is "Attachments", which has a lookup field that can be multiple values of the Standard Codes. 
For expample:

Form List :

- **StandardTitle Code**
  -QAProcess     Q1
  -QARecordForm  Q3 
  -OperationDaily O7

Document List :

- **AttachmentTitle       Code**
  -QAReportSample       Q1,Q3
  -OperationSampleFile  O7
  -QAhours              Q1

In a view of Form List one, there should be the list of files but only those with correct codes.

**Form View 1:**

-StandardTitle:QAProcess
   -Code: Q1
   -DocumentList:

1.QAReportSample
2.QAhours

Here I am looking for:
**Select AttachmentTitle from DocumentList
where Code contains Q1**

The last line is the problem. By default, the lookup field cannot be filtered! 
Anyone please kindly provides some suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Where are you trying to filter? C#?

Comment: Edited to explain the filter. Maybe I have to do C# now.

Comment: Did you try something? Could you add your code?

Comment: It works finally. There are codes I cannot see behind the form because I am migrating from sp 2007 to 2013. I got XML using owssvr.dll. So I worked around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a View for the List and Library. Also you can set view filters for Lookup. Select All Items view or create a new view, and apply filter for Code contains Q1, selected properties to title. Refer the below link.

[SharePoint 2013 List Views](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9)